# Running Ubuntu from a Flash Drive

Tags: 14.04, grub2, system-installation

I need to run Ubuntu 14.04 on a notebook to test certain remote services but I don't want that OS permanently installed on that computer. So I have figured out I could run an Ubuntu installation from a flash drive.

I have downloaded Ubuntu ISO file, made the Live CD, booted up, inserted second flash drive and installed Ubuntu on it. At the beginning of installation I had

**/dev/sda1** with **Windows OS**, **/dev/cdrom** - my first **flash drive with Ubuntu Live CD** and **/dev/sdc** with my **second flash drive**. I have created Ext4 partition on /dev/sdc and got /dev/sdc1. I chose **/dev/sdc1 for installation of Ubuntu** and the same **/dev/sdc1 for GRUB** location. I didn't do a swap as I considered it will use the flash drive heavily and will not be good for the speed sake and also for the flash drive itself.

The installation went through fine.

Now I can choose in my BIOS what drive to boot from. I can boot from the hard drive and get Windows running as it was before. But if I choose to boot from that second flash drive I have installed Ubuntu on I get black screen with a cursor flashing.

Is there something wrong with the Grub settings on that second flash drive? And if so how can I edit that Grub without having a possibility to boot up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how much time do you stay in that black screen until you quit?

Take in account that the USB connection is slower than sata and it will take some time to boot.

I cannot be 100% sure that is not an installation problem, so you can try to edit the files into the flash drive with some software for reading ext4 file system from windows.

Few year ago I install ubuntu in a external drive by USB connection and had no problem with the installation neither working with the system. May be you can try to install Ubuntu again.

Comment: Thank you. I have installed this to another flash drive and it worked. Great!